# How to merge more materials into one

Tags: materials

I have couple of objects in my GLB file.
One object (a chair) has this material:

[image]

and on scene it looks like:

[image]

The second object (group of objects) looks like:

[image]

and on scene:

[image]

My question is: how to merge second object (group) in order to look like first one, and how to merge materials from the second group in order to look like material from first object. I tried to merge objects with ctrl+J but it does not merge materials.

Many thanks!
Mirko

Comment: why do you want to merge the second object?

Comment: Because I am importing GLB into THREE.js and like this I will get 4 different meshes which does not make sense.

Comment: Maybe you need to "bake materials" using Cycles

Comment: Any idea how to do that? Many thanks!